# Pointer to a QDomNode in QDomDocument

Tags: c++, qt, xml-parsing

How can I get a pointer to a concrete `QDomNode` in `QDomDocument`?

```
void MainWindow::traverseNode(const QDomNode& node,int &objectCounter)
{
    QDomNode domNode = node.firstChild();
    while(!domNode.isNull()) {
        if(domNode.isElement()) {
            QDomElement domElement = domNode.toElement();
            if(!domElement.isNull()) {
                domElement.setAttribute("id",QString::number(objectCounter));
                ++objectCounter;
                //and save pointer to this element somewhere
            }
        }
        traverseNode(domNode,objectCounter);
        domNode = domNode.nextSibling();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `&domNode` as a pointer to a concrete `QDomNode`. Looking at the documentation, this will most likely have the effects you want (which are not really well specified in the question):

> Changing the returned node will also change the node in the document tree.

Comment: But how can I use this "pointers" outside the function? QDomNode domNode - local object and outside the function it will be destroyed. Or I'm wrong? (Sorry for my English, I hope, you understand my question)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
domNode = domNode.nextSibling();
m_currentDomNotePointer = &domNode; // You could also use a pointer vector.
```

then you will be able to use this `m_currentDomNotePointer` in another method like this:

```
MyClass::anotherMethod()
{
    // use m_currentDomNotePointer
}
```

But this all seems a bit futile since you could just save `const QDomNode& node` and reuse that similarly as in this method. I do not see why you would like to avoid that unless you only one or a few specific elements of that "container".

Comment: I have my own class "mySvgItem" with field "QDomNode node" and for each item I want to store it's node to have quick access to any attribute.

Comment: But if I try to do something like that:

Comment: create `QVector test` and for each node `test.push_back(&domNode)` as result I will get `QVector` with some wrong links.